# Why I have empty windows logs after success EventWrite function call

Tags: c++, winapi, logging, windows-services, wevtutil

I have a manifest file with several events and two channels.
I generate include and resource file via mc command:

```
mc -um manifest.man
```

I link resource files into the application.

I install manifest in the system via wevtutil command:

```
wevtutil.exe im manifest.man
```

In application I use EventRegister for initialization log, and EventWrite for log writing.
The next code for generating log event return ERROR_SUCCESS:
EVENT_DATA_DESCRIPTOR data;

```
 ULONG writeEvent(const std::string& message){
   std::string log_message_str( message );
   EVENT_DATA_DESCRIPTOR data;
   EVENT_DESCRIPTOR description;
   EventDataDescCreate( &data, message.c_str(), static_cast<ULONG>(log_message_str.size() + 1) );

   return EventWrite(log_handle, &description, 1, &data);
 }
```

Also, I grant read permissions to my application for LocalService:

```
icacls "service_win.exe" /grant "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService":R /Q
```

I start my application such as service with 'NT AUTHORITY\LocalService' account:

```
sc.exe create service_win binpath=D:\service_win.exe type=own obj='NT AUTHORITY\LocalService'
net start service_win
```

The channels declared in my manifest.man added in WinEvents journal, but are empty. 
In the application I write to log via writeEvent every one second with ERROR_SUCCESS result, but my logs files still are empty.

**UPDATE:**

I create [github repo](https://github.com/synacker/windows_local_service) with steps for reproduce

Comment: If possible, show your manifest file so I can try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT may be I know what is the problem - I don't start etw session via StartTrace command in my service.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I created github repo with this issue and steps for reproduce - https://github.com/synacker/windows_local_service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.
The problem was in trace session and auto generated code from [mc utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/message-compiler--mc-exe-).
Need to call mc with -um flag and use auto generated functions for log write.
Working sample is [here](https://github.com/synacker/windows_local_service)

Answer (score 3):

You are using [Event Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/about-event-tracing#missing-events) technology. It requires provider create events and consumer consume events.

If you want to view events via Event Viewer you can refer to [Using Event Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/using-event-logging).

So the issue here is you can't see these events in Event Viewer even if your events write successfully. These events missed because you never start a consumer to consume them.

Refer to [Events lost reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/about-event-tracing#missing-events).

You can find them via ETW logging in [Windows Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-desktop) like this:

[image]

Refer to [Consuming Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/consuming-events) for detailed information about how to consume events.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But, how to write into event viewer in code?

Comment: @synacker Refer to [Reporting Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/reporting-an-event).

Comment: I still not understand. I created two channels via manifest and wevtutil utility in log viewer. How to write events into these channels from service application?

Comment: @synacker ETW and event viewer use different API ([EventWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/evntprov/nf-evntprov-eventwrite)/[ReportEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-reporteventa)) to publish events. You seems mix them. The channel you created is used for ETW but `wevtutil` is used to retrieve events in event viewer. The reporting events sample mentioned is used to send event to event viewer from an application (same with service application).